# How to know if keyboard (dis)appears in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an EditText and want to give it more lines when the keyboard appears.
So i am looking for something like a *"OnKeyboardAppearsListener"* but can't find it.
I think it must exist, but perhaps in a different way...

Answer (score 5):

You have to *@Override* `onConfigurationChanged` to be able to handle runtime changes:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks whether a hardware or on-screen keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) for keyboard related (among others) fields you might want to use.

---

Edit (RivieraKid): Changed to take account of hard or on-screen keyboard.

Comment: That only works for the hardware keyboard though - no notification for the software keyboard is given :(

Comment: You might want to change newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden to newConfig.keyboardHidden which also handles on-screen keyboards.

Comment: I tried it out, but the method onConfigurationChanged is never called...  In the AndroidManifest.xml i have android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard"

Comment: Is `configChanges` attribute associated with the correct activity on your manifest?