# start activity when softinput is gone

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard

I have this code, i have a button and this make appears a edit text and force softinput to apears, and i want to do some stuff when the users ends to input text how i do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText textInput;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private TextView text;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int id = arg0.getId();
        switch(id){
        case R.id.button1:
            processOnClick();
            break;
        }


    } 

 private void processOnClick() {
        text.setVisibility(2);
        textInput.setVisibility(0);
        textInput.setInputType(0x00000001);
        textInput.getWindowVisibility();
        textInput.setCursorVisible(false);
        //textInput.onKeyDown(0x00000009,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(textInput.findFocus(), 0);



    }
```

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link: [How to know if keyboard (dis)appears in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961927/how-to-know-if-keyboard-disappears-in-android)

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks whether a hardware or on-screen keyboard is available
        if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls, use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961927/how-to-know-if-keyboard-disappears-in-android

Comment: did you read this comments:
You might want to change newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden to newConfig.keyboardHidden which also handles on-screen keyboards. – RivieraKid May 11 '11 at 10:03  
Never mind - did it for you ;-) – RivieraKid May 11 '11 at 10:21  
I tried it out, but the method onConfigurationChanged is never called... In the AndroidManifest.xml i have android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard" – PitjDroid May 11 '11 at 10:26  
Is configChanges attribute associated with the correct activity on your manifest? – Jota May 11 '11 at 11:00

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you determine that "the users ends to input text".

If you can take it that the user is waiting for the program to respond 3 seconds after he has given input (say), you do as follows:

1. Add a          [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to the `EditText`. Everytime the text changes, you will be notified  through callbacks.
2. After every input, start a `Thread` which sleeps    for the    pre-determined time (3 seconds) If the sleep is completed,       then    start the `Activity`.  If the user inputs text before the sleep        is completed, interrupt the Thread and start over.

A more straight forward implementation would be to provide a button which says something like "Go" or "Start" so that the user is not taken by surprise, and you don't do anything unintented.

Comment: at last i will put the botton but i want to avoid it